# Where clause in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a question about SQLAlchemy.

Currently I have two models using Flask - SQLAlchemy :

```
class Action(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'ACTION'

    _FIELDS_LABELS = ("ID", "MODULE_ID", "CATEGORY", "LABEL", "COMMAND", "ARGS", "FILE_ID")
    _REPR_FIELDS = ("MODULE_NAME", "FILE_NAME")

    id = db.Column(_FIELDS_LABELS[0], db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    module_id = db.Column(_FIELDS_LABELS[1], db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('MODULE.ID'))
    category = db.Column(_FIELDS_LABELS[2], db.String())
    label = db.Column(_FIELDS_LABELS[3], db.String())
    command = db.Column(_FIELDS_LABELS[4], db.String())
    args = db.Column(_FIELDS_LABELS[5], db.String())
    file_id = db.Column(_FIELDS_LABELS[6], db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('FILE.ID'))

    file = db.relationship('File')
```

and

```
class Module(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'MODULE'

    _FIELDS_LABELS = ("ID", "NAME")

    id = db.Column(_FIELDS_LABELS[0], db.Integer,  primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(_FIELDS_LABELS[1], db.String(), unique=True)
    actions = db.relationship('Action')
```

With Flask I try to get actions with URL like that :

```
http://ip:port/modules/0/actions/18
```

So I have an action blueprint :

```
action_blueprint = Blueprint('action',
                             __name__,
                             url_prefix="/modules/<string:module_id>/actions")
```

And route :

```
@action_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def read_all(module_id):

    if module_id == '*':
        if len(request.args) == 0:
            actions = Action.query.all()
            return jsonify(list_to_json(actions))
        else:
            try:
                action = Action.query.filter_by(**request.args.to_dict()).first()
                return jsonify(action.serialize)
            except InvalidRequestError as i:
                return json_response(400, "InvalidRequestError : {}".format(i.args))
    else:
        try:
            module = Module.query.get(module_id)
        except AttributeError as a:
            return json_response(400, "'{}' needed to be '*' or a number.".format(module_id))

        if len(request.args) == 0:
            return jsonify(actions=list_to_json(module.actions))

        action = Action.query.join(Module).filter(Module.id == module_id).filter_by(**request.args.to_dict()).first()
        return jsonify(action.serialize)
```

But I have the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

The generated query :

```
SELECT "ACTION"."ID" AS "ACTION_ID", "ACTION"."MODULE_ID" AS "ACTION_MODULE_ID", "ACTION"."CATEGORY" AS "ACTION_CATEGORY", "ACTION"."LABEL" AS "ACTION_LABEL", "ACTION"."COMMAND" AS "ACTION_COMMAND", "ACTION"."ARGS" AS "ACTION_ARGS", "ACTION"."FILE_ID" AS "ACTION_FILE_ID"
FROM "ACTION" JOIN "MODULE" ON "MODULE"."ID" = "ACTION"."MODULE_ID"
WHERE "MODULE"."ID" = ? AND "MODULE"."ID" = ?
```

There is a probleme with the end of the query, but I don't really know if

```
action = Action.query.join(Module).filter(Module.id == module_id).filter_by(**request.args.to_dict()).first()
```

is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is somewhat obvious from looking at the produced query.

```
WHERE "MODULE"."ID" = ? AND "MODULE"."ID" = ?
```

should indicate that there's something amiss, unless both values are the same, in which case the predicate is redundant. It is clear that

```
request.args.to_dict()
```

produces a dictionary like

```
{ 'id': <some value> }
```

This is clear because of how [`Query.filter_by()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) works:

> The keyword expressions are extracted from the primary entity of the query, **or the last entity that was the target of a call to `Query.join()`**.

So in your case it extracts the id attribute of Module and adds the filtering criterion `Module.id == <some value>`. The fix depends on what your request args are for.

Also because [`Query.first()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first) may return None, you should somehow account for that.

```
action = Action.query...first()

if action:
    return jsonify(action.serialize)

else:
    # Handle not found
```

Comment: Thanks.
This is the request I currently use.
But it's not a filter on the actions of the specified module.

Comment: That may be, but in your example the request args dict has a key *id*, which is then extracted from Module with your current code. I forgot to add in the answer that all in all since `Query.first()` may very well return None, you should prepare for that. You really should add such details in the question. Now it is entirely unclear what the request.args actually are and what for, other than the observed effects.